# Is it possible to apply color effects to an image?

Tags: php

any one guide me is it possible to apply color effects to an image using php?

as mentioned in the screen shot i want to select Ice,Black,Crystal etc.. color effect from the top and it should be applied to image selected below?

[image]

or any useful solution?

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you use ImageMagick?

Comment: GD's [imagefilter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagefilter.php)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the [GD library](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) in PHP which I used successfully some time ago.

Comment: can i apply any kind of color using this library?

Comment: @UMAR: I imagine you can, but you'd have to experiment to get the effects you want.

Comment: I do think you could draw a second image with a single color in memory and then overlay the new with your existing image with an alpha channel, something similar to what [this guy](http://koivi.com/php-gd-image-watermark/) does.

Comment: imagecopymerge is one that might be useful for straight color filters: you'd create a temporary image in memory, flood fill it with a configurable color, then merge it with a percentage parameter less than 100%

Answer (score 0):

I'd highly recommend installing [imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) on your server and then installing the [imagick PHP extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php).  Imagemagick is extremely powerful and basically functions like a command-line Photoshop.

Answer (score 0):

This function takes an image, then lets you add red, green, or blue to the image. You can also use negative numbers when calling this function, to create a lack of color.

```
function shade($image,$r=0,$g=0,$b=0){
$width=imagesx($image);
$height=imagesy($image);
$aw=0;
$ah=0;
for(;;){
if ($aw==$width) {$aw=0; $ah++;}
if ($ah==$height) break;
$rgb = imagecolorat($image, $aw, $ah);
$colors = imagecolorsforindex($image, $rgb);
$ar = $colors['red'];
$ag = $colors['green'];
$ab = $colors['blue'];
$ar+=$r;
$ag+=$g;
$ab+=$b;
if ($ar>255) $ar=255;
if ($ag>255) $ag=255;
if ($ab>255) $ab=255;
if ($ar<0) $ar=0;
if ($ag<0) $ag=0;
if ($ab<0) $ab=0;
$newcolor = imagecolorallocate($image, $ar, $ag, $ab);
$black = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 55, 0);
imagesetpixel ($image , $aw , $ah , $newcolor );
$aw++;
}//end loop
return $image;
}
```

Comment: Also, I want to add that I wrote this function myself, and that it seems to work without any issues.

Comment: what about ice and crystal effect if i want to apply on an image? as given in image? can i apply also? and how?

Answer (score 0):

You should check out [pslayers](https://github.com/darrynten/pslayers) it will enable you to do what you're wanting to do.